# PayU API Integration on Android does not work

Tags: android, payu

I have had multiple issues while integrating PayU on android. I wonder what I am missing.

1. The integration expects importing projects and then adding as dependency into my android app. But the build fails if I don't select version Android 5.0.1. Does this mean that PayU wont support anything less than 5.0.1?
2. Finally I integrated the API and added the project after making some changes to their code.

   During install

   ```
   [2015-09-17 17:34:24 - app] Success!
   [2015-09-17 17:34:24 - PayU] Could not find PayU.apk!
   [2015-09-17 17:34:24 - app] Starting activity com.app.SearchFlight on device 104155f6
   [2015-09-17 17:34:25 - app] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
   [2015-09-17 17:34:25 - app] Please check logcat output for more details.
   [2015-09-17 17:34:25 - app] Launch canceled!
   [2015-09-17 17:34:27 - app] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.mcruiseon.app/com.app.SearchFlight }
   ```

   After launch

   ```
   09-17 17:34:44.526: E/AndroidRuntime(24140): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   09-17 17:34:44.526: E/AndroidRuntime(24140): Process: com.mcruiseon.app, PID: 24140
   09-17 17:34:44.526: E/AndroidRuntime(24140): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.payu.sdk.PayU
   09-17 17:34:44.526: E/AndroidRuntime(24140):    at com.app.SearchFlight.onClick(SearchFlight.java:380)
   09-17 17:34:44.526: E/AndroidRuntime(24140):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
   09-17 17:34:44.526: E/AndroidRuntime(24140):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18457)
   09-17 17:34:44.526: E/AndroidRuntime(24140):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   09-17 17:34:44.526: E/AndroidRuntime(24140):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   09-17 17:34:44.526: E/AndroidRuntime(24140):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   09-17 17:34:44.526: E/AndroidRuntime(24140):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
   09-17 17:34:44.526: E/AndroidRuntime(24140):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   09-17 17:34:44.526: E/AndroidRuntime(24140):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   09-17 17:34:44.526: E/AndroidRuntime(24140):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   09-17 17:34:44.526: E/AndroidRuntime(24140):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
   09-17 17:34:44.526: E/AndroidRuntime(24140):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   09-17 17:34:46.316: I/Process(24140): Sending signal. PID: 24140 SIG: 9
   ```

What am I missing here? Is [this](https://github.com/PayU/paytouch-android) their latest version?

**Solution**

I moved away from PayU. I wonder how companies survive with bugs in their `getting started`.

Comment: Follow the link for payu india https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App/releases/tag/s4.3.6c6m1.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that you overlooked this on their [github page](https://github.com/PayU/paytouch-android)

> **Beware that this SDK works only in Poland**

Since you seem to be located in India, it's most likely not going to work, even if you manage to "install" it properly. It might be better to look for an alternative.

Apart from that

> Does this mean that PayU wont support anything less than 5.0.1?

No, it supports Android 2.3 and up. That is stated on the page you link to.

[Here](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App) is a github page with example code for an android project.